# Get Yammer user data

Tags: api, admin, visualization, yammer, user-data

I'm creating a dashboard in Splunk to visualize various activities in Yammer. For example, the interactions and collaboration between each team, user participation rate, top-viewed posts etc. But I'm having trouble retrieving needed information. I have Yammer verified admin access but I do not think exported data using `export users` from `network admin` contain enough information.(Please refer to the link below)

So I was wondering if there's any other method retrieving more user data? What about REST API? Is it possible to get all users data at once? Thanks in advance!

[Export data from Yammer Enterprise](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-data-from-yammer-enterprise-b303d8f3-007d-4ad4-81f8-54fb1ecfb3f2)

[REST API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download all Yammer network data using the network level export documented here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api

There might be some data you need that is better retrieved from the REST API, like users in a group or users who liked a message. These endpoints are documented starting here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits

Comment: If anyone is looking at this as of January 2019, it should be noted that the schema information for the data export API in the Yammer developer documentation is not correct and hasn't been for four or five months.
If you develop any scripts for using the data export API and consuming the CSV files it generates, test with real data and monitor for failures, because there is a bit of a track record of making breaking changes to this API with little notice given.